Paste the value of a shell expression into Vim
I need to make the text returned by echo $(which bash) available for pasting in a text file opened in Vim.
The cause of my confusion is that it seems there are at least three clipboards:

system clipboard (e.g., Command-C > Command-V)
shell clipboard (e.g., Control-U > Control-Y)
Vim clipboard (e.g., yy > p)

So, in order to accomply my task, I can, for example, type echo $(which bash) | pbcopy, open Vim, and then press Command-V.
This works, but I'm not sure this is how non-newbie Vim users would prefer to do it, because in such a case Vim reads from the system clipboard, and reading from the system clipboard has many nuances: e.g., whether your Vim is compiled with a specific option, whether you have appropriate setting in your .vimrc, etc.
What is a more correct way to accomply this?

Delete here and repost to [vi.se] ?

Where it is comprehensively covered at https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/96/205

@Stewart Is there any difference between these commands? I mean, maybe the longer version is more robust, more versatile?

And in addition to that, since $(which bash) is unquoted, the output will be subject to field splitting and filename expansion (unlikely to result in any changes with default IFS and the likely output for which bash), but still troublesome for commands in general: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98436/70524

Instead of using the clip-board, this use-case is perfect for :r!
:r! echo $(which bash)


: enters command mode
r means we will read something (if we don't include !, then it will read a file).
! means we will execute a process.  The stdout will be fed into the r and inserted into our document.

Note that in a best-case scenario, echo isn't very useful here.  which bash already returns something like /usr/bin/bash, so we're just running echo /usr/bin/bash which outputs /usr/bin/bash.  In a worst case scenario, the process you run could output echo's options, like -e or some escape sequences like \b, or output something with an IFS= character.  That could cause echo to interpret its input and take actions instead of printing it verbatim.  Therefore, I'd recommend to drop the echo (or at least replace it with a printf).
:r! which bash


Here's an example of how I use :r! in my every-day life.  If I'm trying to add unversioned files to svn:ignore (a property of subversion similar to .gitignore), I'll do this:
export EDITOR=vim
svn propedit svn:ignore .

Then, in vim, I can:
:r! svn status | awk '/^\?/{ print $2 }'
:wq

That will call svn status which lists all modified, missing, unversioned, new, deleted files.  Then I use awk to focus on anything that starts with a ? (indicating unversioned), then print the filename.  vim inserts the result into my svn:ignore temporary file, and the :wq will exit the editor and set the property.

If you're on macos as per the question tags, then the default Vim has clipboard support:
% /usr/bin/vim --version | grep -wo -e '.clipboard' -e '.*version.*'
macOS version - arm64
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+clipboard

So if the content is already copied into the system clipboard (using pbcopy, CmdC, or some other means), then use "+p or "*p (or P, depending on how you want to paste). On macOS both + and * are equivalent. This works without any additional vimrc configuration (e.g., when running vim -u NONE or vim --clean).

I don't have a mapping of Vim versions to macOS versions, but any recent macOS should have a version of Vim with the :terminal command (added in 2017), with which you can run a terminal inside Vim, and access the contents of that terminal for copy-paste within Vim. Use :term to start a terminal, run commands, use C-w N to go into Terminal-Normal mode, copy and select the text as you normally would in Normal mode, switch to the buffer you want to paste as you normally would, and paste as you normally would.
